# Django on Google Cloud: css files blocked due to MIME type mismatch

Tags: python, django, gcloud

I'm attempting to set up a Django 3.0 API on a Google Cloud Flexible environment (using Gunicorn to serve). The API itself works but when I attempt to navigate the the Django admin page, all of the css files fail to load giving the error:

`The resource was blocked due to MIME type ("text/html") mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)`

I would like to change the MIME type rather than getting rid of `nosniff` but I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to do either. I will need to serve both `css` and `js` files. This is my first Django application so I'm not 100% sure what information will be helpful, but here is my `settings.py` file:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '127.0.0.1', # For local deployment
    'xxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com' # Gcloud URL
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'drf_yasg',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'django_nose',
    'myapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
  <redacted>
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json',
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema',
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
STATIC_URL = 'gs://myapp-static/static/' # static files in their own bucket. I have confirmed they are accessible.

TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--with-coverage',
    '--cover-package=myapp',
]
```

and possibly relevant lines from my Google cloud `app.yaml`

```
runtime: custom
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT myapp.wsgi --timeout 120
env: flex # for Google Cloud Flexible App Engine
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?